# Implementar Salvar como e Salvar em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Sabe aquela diferença básica entre o **salvar** e o **salvar como** dos editores de texto? Então, eu estou querendo por em minha aplicação apenas a opção "salvar", porém, após pesquisar muito na net só descobrir a forma **salvar como** que envolve o uso do OpenFileDialog, queria saber como por no meu save uma opção onde ele salva a alteração no texto sem abrir o OpenFileDialog.

Esse foi o melhor que conseguir, usando o Open:

```
 SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        sfd.RestoreDirectory = true;
        sfd.FileName = "*.txt";
        sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
        sfd.Filter = "txt files (*.txt) | *.txt";

        if(sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Stream fileStream = sfd.OpenFile();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);

            sw.Write(JanelaDeTxt.Text);

            sw.Close();
            fileStream.Close();           
        }
```

Comment: Para isso, você já tem que saber o path de onde será salvo, correto? Se não, ele vai salvar onde? Neste caso, apenas passe o path para salvar como argumento para `StreamWriter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma vez quando você salvar o arquivo, precisará antes especificar o local de onde este arquivo está. Quando é a primeira vez que irá salvar o arquivo, é indiferente a ação do botão *Salvar* e *Salvar como*, porque ambos necessitarão de um local absoluto de onde salvará o arquivo.

Após o primeiro salvamento, o botão *Salvar* já poderá funcionar sozinho. O *Salvar como* terá sua mesma função, abrir o diálogo e fazer o usuário escolher onde salvar o arquivo.

Para o botão *Salvar*, você pode fazer uma simples condicional com uma variável em escopo a nível de classe onde armazena o último local que o arquivo foi salvo. Se essa variável for vazia, logo o botão *Salvar* aciona a função do *Salvar como*. Nas instruções do *Salvar como*, atribui o valor do local a esta variável.

```
class Form1 {
   public string LastSaveLocation = "";

   public void SalvarComo() {
      SaveFileDialog sv = new SaveFileDialog() { .Filter = "Arquivos de texto|*.txt" };
      sv.ShowDialog();

      if (sv.Filename != "") {
         LastSaveLocation = sv.Filename;
         System.IO.File.WriteAllText(LastSaveLocation, JanelaDeTxt.Text);
      }
   }

   public void Salvar() {
      if (LastSaveLocation == "") {
         SalvarComo();
      } else {
         System.IO.File.WriteAllText(LastSaveLocation, JanelaDeTxt.Text);
      }
   }
}
```

No código acima, `LastSaveLocation` terá o local do arquivo que foi salvo usando o `SalvarComo`. Ele sempre será atualizado se o usuário determinar outro lugar para salvar.

Associe estes métodos aos seus botões de *Salvar* e *Salvar como*, e também não se esqueça de declarar o `LastSaveLocation` como uma variável de instância ao escopo da classe.

Comment: thank very much!